# Ajax not working Or is it PHP query?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm not sure where does the problem line. So I will give a brief description here: I'm trying to build a web application from scratch with PHP. With this, I want the page to ajax almost every forms. I created 2 classes (User and Client). The code should handle a form to submit to the database via another PHP file.

```
class User{
  public static function edit ($id, $user, $pass, $is_admin, $client){
      global $db;
      $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $id);
      $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $user);
      $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $pass);
      $is_admin = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $is_admin);
      $client = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $client);
      if ($_SESSION['user']['is_admin'] == true){
        if ($client == '')
          $client = 'NULL';
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET users.username = '{$user}', users.password = '{$pass}', users.is_admin = {$is_admin}, ";
        $sql .= "users.client = '{$client}' WHERE users.id = {$id};";
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        if ($db->affected_rows > 0) {
          $_SESSION['success'] = array( 1 => "All changes with the User has been saved." );
        } else {
          $_SESSION['errors'] = array( 1 => "No changes are made. Please contact the Administration for further assistance if needed." );
        }
      }
    }
}
class Client{
  public static function edit ($id, $name, $logo, $street, $city, $state, $zip, $phone, $email, $active){
    global $db;
    $sql = "UPDATE clients SET name=?, logo=?, street=?, city=?, state=?, zip_code=?, phone=?, email=?, active=? WHERE id=?;";
    if ($stmt = $db->prepare($sql) and $_SESSION['user']['is_admin'] == true) {
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $logo);
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $street);
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $city);
      $stmt->bind_param('d', $state);
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $zip);
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $phone);
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
      $stmt->bind_param('d', $active);
      $stmt->bind_param('d', $id);
      $stmt->excute();
      if ($db->affected_rows > 0) {
        $_SESSION['success'] = array( 1 => "All changes with the Client has been saved." );
      } else {
        $_SESSION['errors'] = array( 1 => $db->error );
      }
    } else $_SESSION['errors'] = array( 1 => $db->error );
  }
}
```

The javascript code to handle ajax form is here:

```
function editUser() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'editUser.php',
    data: $('#editUserForm').serialize(),
    cache: false,
    dataType:'json'
  }).always(function(){
    renderUsers();
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
  });
  return false;
}

function editClient() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'editClient.php',
    data: $('#editClientForm').serialize(),
    cache: false,
    dataType:'json',
    error: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  }).always(function(){
    renderUsers();
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
  });;
  return false;
}
```

PHP code to execute the ajax submit for User aka editUser.php file:

```
<?php
  require_once('class_lib.php');
  if($_SESSION['user']['is_admin'] == true){
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
      User::edit($_POST['id'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['is_admin'], $_POST['client']);
    }
  }
?>
```

And this is the editClient.php

```
<?php
  require_once('class_lib.php');
  if($_SESSION['user']['is_admin'] == true){
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
      Client::edit($_POST['id'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['logo'], $_POST['street'], $_POST['city'], $_POST['state'], $_POST['zip_code'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['active']);
    }
    if($_POST['process'] == 'newClient'){
      Client::add();
    }
  }
?>
```

The code are almost identical (I copied and pasted), I created the User functions first and it worked so I moved on with Client and here comes the error. User functionality is still working perfectly, but the Client is not. I created 2 dummy clients to test editing. First client print no errors (`$db->error`) but the second dummy client output this `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' clients.phone = '',clients.email = '', clients.active = 1 WHERE clients.id = 2' at line 1`
I stuck here for a day now and still don't know why is it not working.
More information: I tested the class function, it worked. Test sending the form normal way, it worked. Is it because of ajax not sending the right data? And why the first client doesn't show error? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Change Query using prepare statement method instead of escape_string.

There is no error shown but the statement is not executed.

Comment: Echo the query before you run it and check if it looks correct.

Comment: I use integer for those 3 fields. Do I still need quotes for integer fields?

Comment: OK, no you don't. In that case, you need to print out the full SQL and take a look at it.

Comment: No you don't, but you shouldn't escape integers with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, since it does what it says, escaping _strings_. Cast it as integer instead, with something like: `$var = (int) $_POST['key']` instead, or even better, use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: You should be using parameterised queries anyway, that would prevent SQL injection attacks and you don't need to worry about escaping strings and whether you have quoted them.

Comment: Also, are you *really* using an int for the zip code? That seems quite unusual.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk.

Comment: Hi, I change to the prepare statement approach, change field zipcode to varchar(5). When I try to run, there is no error statement for client but still there is no database changed. Do you know what is the problem now?